# About new client ID

Tags: autodesk-forge

I just register a new ID and unfortunately, there are no forge APIs. Does it be packaged or put into another product?How can I get the new version of forge API? Many thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not clear what, if anything, this has to do with programming.

Comment: The question is about gaining access to the Forge APIs, so (although not directly about programming) it is relevant to anyone interested in the autodesk-forge tag. I've answered it now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post explains - https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accounts-apps-keys-and-ids.

(Basically, you've created an Autodesk Id, but you've not activated your Forge trial).